# OBJ import doesnt work

Tags: import, file-format, error

Since a few days my Blender fails to import .OBJ files and I don't know whats wrong.
It worked fine 2 days ago and I did not change anything in this time.

I tried everything now and even a reinstallation didn't work.

[image: Error message]

Comment: "*I did not change anything in this time*" Not even the imported file?

Comment: nope (i tried other files to be sure)

Comment: actually i got it fixed myself.

Comment: somehow Blender had 3 different directories in my system, don´t ask me why. so i rearranged the files and put them all into one folder and it worked somehow. Thank god i had backups from my Userprefs and startup file. But still, thank you.